# My application records and plays sound using AVAudioPlayer, starting for example from the fifth playback it gives an error

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I record and play sound using AVAudioPlayer, everything works fine in the simulator, but on the device, for example, starting from playing the fifth record, it gives the error "Open failed
The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671.)"

I changed the audio format from m4a to caf, the console does not give an error, but there is still no sound from the next playback.
My code:

```
  func playByUrl(url: String) {
        let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(url).m4a")
     do {
         try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
         try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
         player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFilename, fileTypeHint:     AVFileType.caf.rawValue)
         guard let player = player else { return }
         player.prepareToPlay()
         player.play()
     } catch let error {
         print(error.localizedDescription)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //ask for record permission. IMPORTANT: Make sure you've set `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` in your Info.plist

var localRecordingURL : URL {
        getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.caf")
    }

func requestPermissionForRecording()
{
     AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if allowed {
                self.canRecordAudio = true
            } else {
                self.canRecordAudio = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

check this code while recording setting user voice

```
func recordAudioFile() {
        do {
            //set the audio session so we can record
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
            self.canRecord = false
            fatalError()
        }
        //this describes the format the that the file will be recorded in
        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]
        do {
            //create the recorder, pointing towards the URL from above
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: localRecordingURL,
                                                settings: settings)
            audioRecorder?.record() //start the recording
            isRecording = true
        } catch {
            print(error)
            isRecording = false
        }
    }
```

then run the playsound of recording

```
func playRecordedFile() {
        guard let audioFileURL = audioFileURL else {
            return
        }
        do {
            //create a player, again pointing towards the same URL
            self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFileURL)
            self.audioPlayer?.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

I hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your help, my code matches yours. What worries me is that everything works like clockwork on the simulator.

Comment: My mistake was in AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory I used playback and you need it as you playAndRecord, but then there was a problem with playback not through the speaker, it helped try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)